# The title bar buttons for "chrome" are different than usual applications(according to theme)

Tags: google-chrome, themes, gnome-shell

The problem is that the the title bar buttons are different as shown in this image:

[image: Chrome title bar buttons]

For other applications it's normal, it's according to the theme.

[image: Normal applications]

it's weird and annoying can some one fix this?
[image]

Comment: It's Ubuntu-Gnome 17.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very easy fix :)

Simply check the <kbd>Use system title bar and borders</kbd> option in the Appearance category in Chrome's settings.

Comment: I can't see any title bar icons now...Help?. They were just gone.

Answer (score 3):

go to setting and search theme and check **system title bar and borders** - it'll work, but for me when i maximize chrome title bar button disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Settings - Appearance" and tick "Use system title bar and borders"

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the chrome settings and then go to the `appearance` tab and you get the first option as `Themes` section and at the right side of `themes` option you will   see two more buttons which are `use classics` and `use gtk`

select the `use gtk` option

now you can see the difference

Comment: Is this Answer solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

> go to setting and search theme and check system title bar and borders
>   - it'll work, but for me when i maximize chrome title bar button disappear.

For those people who has this problem, just restart Chrome. It's works for me.