# Titlebar buttons are too big on Chrome

Tags: 18.04, titlebar

I don't know why the titlebar buttons are too big on Chrome, on Firefox or other applications just look fit(Gnome-OSC theme).

[image]

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914744/the-title-bar-buttons-for-chrome-are-different-than-usual-applicationsaccordi/914747) can fix the problem, but I don't want to have an extra title bar.